# HAProxy - ssl client ca chain cannot be verified

Tags: haproxy, openssl, certificate

Situation:

I want this to work:
requests come from clients and goes to haproxy through 443 port (ssl) and then it must go to backend on 80 port.

I have server certificate given by intermediate ca (ca1), ca1 certificate and client certificate. 
BUT I didn't find solution to request correct server certificate from windows certification authority to haproxy server(ubuntu). may be cause of templates.
I requested from windows machine server certificate and copy it to haproxy.

AND PROBLEM IS HAProxy log have this error "ssl client ca chain cannot be verified"

config haproxy:

> frontend https_frontend
>
> bind 192.168.14.167:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cert/request/server.pem  ca-file /etc/haproxy/cert/request/ca1-certificate.pem verify optional crt-ignore-err all no-sslv3
>
> mode http
>
> log /dev/log  local7
>
> option httplog
>
> use_backend web_server_1 if { ssl_fc_has_crt }
>
> default_backend web_server_2
>
> > backend web_server_1
> >
> > mode http
> >
> > option httplog
> >
> > server w7 192.168.11.109:80 check
> >
> > backend web_server_2
> >
> > mode http
> >
> > option httplog
> >
> > server xp 192.168.13.205:80 check

this scheme doesn't work.

additional info: log from winXP, where I ran opennssl

C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl s_client -connect haproxy2:443 -cert client.pem -CAfile
 ca1-certificate.pem -state -showcerts

316:error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:.\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1275:SSL alert number 48

316:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_lib.c:184:
... cer info...
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

(sorry for my english if it bad)
I have read many posts about it but didn't find solution.

Answer (score 2):

The files server.pem and client.pem should have 3 sections in it and should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<lots of base64 encoded data>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<lots of base64 encoded data>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<lots of base64 encoded data>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The private key might not be RSA, but it should be first. The first certificate is the signed server certificate. The second certificate should be the CA certificate. You can copy and paste each section using a text editor. To check your certificate, run this.

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca1-certificate.pem server.pem
server.pem: OK
```